# A functor continuous with respect to a cylinder

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

In the erratum of their paper: **“Categories of continuous functors, I”, (Journal of Pure and Appplied Algebra 2 (1972) 169–191)**, the authors, P.J. Freyd and G.M. Kelly, define the continuity of a functor $T: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{A}$ relative to a “cylinder” $\alpha$ as follows:

1. First, they define a “cylinder” as the 4-uple made of $(J, P, Q, \alpha)$ where $J \colon \mathcal{K} \to \mathcal{L}$, $P \colon \mathcal{L} \to \mathcal{C}$ and $Q \colon \mathcal{K} \to \mathcal{C}$ are functors, and $\alpha \colon PJ \xrightarrow{\cdot} Q \colon \mathcal{K} \to \mathcal{C}$ is a natural transformation. (They refer to the cylinder $(J, P, Q, \alpha)$ writing it simply as $\alpha$).
2. Then, they define: $T$ is continuous relative to the cylinder $\alpha$ if and only if the composite
   $$
     \lim\,TP \to \lim\, TPJ \to \lim\, TQ
     \tag{1}
   $$
   is an isomorphism, “the first map being the canonical one and the second being $\lim\, T$”.

My question is:

**What exactly are those morphisms appearing in equation (1)?**

For example, for the functor $T \colon \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{A}$ the standard definition for the limit of $T$ is a pair $(\overline {\lim\,T}, \overline{T})$ where $\overline{\lim\,T} \in \mathrm{Obj}_{\mathcal{A}}$, and $\overline{T} \colon (\overline{\lim\,T})_{\mathcal{C}} \xrightarrow{\cdot} T \colon \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{A}$.

Then, in what sense is the second morphism in eq. (1), $\lim\, TPJ \to \lim\, TQ$, related to the limit of $T$, understood here as being the natural transformation $\overline{T}$?

And what is the “canonical map” $\lim\,TP \to \lim\, TPJ$?

Comment: I'm looking at the paper and it seems to me as if they define a "cylinder" simply as a natural transformation between two functors into $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: Yes, this is what they define as cylinder in the introduction of their paper, but if you see the erratum it seems they changed this definition of cylinder as to corresponds to the form I wrote in my question.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you have a diagram $X\colon\mathcal{I}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$ and a morphism $T\colon\mathcal{J}\rightarrow\mathcal{I}$, there is a canonical morphism $\lim X\rightarrow\lim XT$. This, by the universal property, corresponds to giving compatible morphisms $\lim X\rightarrow XT(j)$ for each object $j\in\mathcal{J}$ and the canonical choice is taking the canonical projections. The first morphism is a special case of this.

Whenever you have diagrams $X,Y\colon\mathcal{I}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$ and a natural transformation $\alpha\colon X\Rightarrow Y$, there is a canonical morphism $\lim\alpha\colon\lim X\rightarrow\lim Y$. This, by the universal property, corresponds to giving compatible morphisms $\lim X\rightarrow Y(i)$ for each object $i\in\mathcal{I}$ and the canonical choice is taking the composition $\lim X\rightarrow X(i)\rightarrow Y(i)$ of the canonical projection and $\alpha(i)$. The second morphism is a special case of this.

Answer (score 3):

There are two kinds of construction going on here (that are probably special cases of one general construction).

- Let $P \colon \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ be a functor and let $J \colon \mathcal{B} \to \mathcal{C}$ be another functor.
  There exists a unique morphism
  $$
    r \colon \lim P \to \lim PJ
  $$
  with $\mathrm{pr}_B ∘ r = \mathrm{pr}_{J(B)}$ for every object $B$ of $\mathcal{B}$, i.e., such that the diagram
  $$
    \require{AMScd}
    \begin{CD}
      \lim P                     @> r >> \lim PJ \\
      @V \mathrm{pr}_{J(B)} VV           @VV \mathrm{pr}_B V \\
      PJ(B)                      @=      PJ(B)
    \end{CD}
  $$
  commutes for every object $B$ of $\mathcal{B}$.

  For some intuition on this, one can consider the case that the category $\mathcal{C}$ is discrete, $\mathcal{B}$ is a subcategory of $\mathcal{C}$, and $J$ is the inclusion functor from $\mathcal{B}$ to $\mathcal{C}$.
  Then $\lim P = \prod_C P(C)$ and $\lim PJ = \prod_B PJ(B) = \prod_B P(B)$.
  The morphism $r$ goes from the larger product $\prod_C P(C)$ into the smaller product $\prod_B P(B)$ by throwing some of the factors away.

  Suppose more generally that $\mathcal{B}$ is a subcategory of $\mathcal{C}$ and that $J$ is the inclusion functor from $\mathcal{B}$ to $\mathcal{C}$.
  The functor $P$ describes a diagram in $\mathcal{D}$.
  The term $\lim P$ is the limit of the entire diagram, whereas $\lim PJ$ is the limit over only a part of the diagram.
- Let $P, Q \colon \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ be two functors and let $α \colon P \Rightarrow Q$ be a natural transformation.
  There exists a unique morphism
  $$
    \lim α \colon \lim P \to \lim Q
  $$
  with $\mathrm{pr}_C ∘ \lim α = α_C ∘ \mathrm{pr}_C$ for every object $C$ of $\mathcal{C}$, i.e., such that the diagram
  $$
    \require{AMScd}
    \begin{CD}
      \lim P                @> \lim α >>   \lim Q              \\
      @V \mathrm{pr}_C VV                  @VV \mathrm{pr}_C V \\
      P(C)                  @> α_C >>      Q(C)
    \end{CD}
  $$
  commutes for every object $C$ of $\mathcal{C}$.

  This construction is essentially how the functoriality of
  $$
    \lim \colon \mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{D}) \to \mathcal{D}
  $$
  works.

  As a specific example, suppose that $\mathcal{C}$ is discrete with two objects, named $1$ and $2$.
  Then $\lim P = P(1) × P(2)$ and $\lim Q = Q(1) × Q(2)$, and $\lim α = α_1 × α_2$.

In your specific case, the morphism from $\lim TP$ to $\lim TPJ$ comes from the first construction.
The morphism from $\lim TPJ$ to $\lim TQ$ comes from the second construction and the whiskered natural transformation $T α \colon TPJ \Rightarrow TQ$.